# In SqlAlchemy how to test if an attribute a Column or just plain attribute

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have defined some classes inheriting the declarative_base, like this:

```
class SomeClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'some_table'
    id = Column("some_table_id", Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(Text)
    some_other_data = "some_other_data"
```

When doing a report, I'd like to automatically grab those Column attribute while leaving non-Column attributes alone. Is there a way to test this?

Answer (score 0):

You can gt all the Model class columns using:

```
for c in SomeClass.__table__.columns:
    print(c)
```

**Output:**

```
some_table.some_table_id
some_table.data
```

This will not give you other plain attributes of that class.

If you want to fetch data of your table fields (Columns), use above code in following way

```
result = session.query(*[c for c in SomeClass.__table__.c]).all()
print(result)
```

Where `session` is the DB connection.